# Why T in "K <: T" can't be covariance?

Tags: scala, type-systems, type-bounds

Scala code:

```
class Cat[T] {
    def meow[K <: T] = ""
}

class Cat[-T] {
    def meow[K <: T] = ""
}
```

They can be compiled.

But when `T` is covariance, the following code can't be compiled:

```
class Cat[+T] {
    def meow[K <: T] = ""
}
```

The compiler prints:

```
error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type  <: T of type K
       def meow[K <: T] = ""
                ^
```

The type on the right of `<:` must not be covariant? And why?

Comment: `T in “K <: T” can't be covariance` only available at negative positions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be unsound

with `Jazz <: Music`, `Classical <: Music`, but no relation between `Jazz` and `Classical`,

`meow[K <: T]` means that a `Cat[Music]` can meow in `Jazz`, `Classical`, or any choice of genre.

On the other hand, a `Cat[Classical]` meow cannot be `Jazz`.

But if you have covariant `Cat[+T]`, then a `Cat[Classical] <: Cat[Music]` , so a `Cat[Classical]`, being an eclectic `Cat[Music]` too, should be able to meow `Jazz`.

Contradiction.